# Why do we have different aliyot for the same section of the Torah?

Tags: torah-reading, chagim-holidays

We lane (read) the same section for the first Yom Tov of Sukkot and the second day of Pesach. I've noticed, however, that even though שלישי is in the same place, לוי isn't. Why would this be?

Comment: In my siddur (Tehillas Hashem) it's exactly the same. Do you want to edit into your question which siddur, as well as where the breaks are? Levi is from אלה מועדי ה and Shlishi starts וספרתם לכם on both occasions.

Comment: @Michoel Is yours talking about second day of pesach in Israel where there are only 3 total aliyot?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's entitled קריאה בארץ ישראל ליום ראשון דחול המועד, ובחו"ל - יום טוב שני של פסח and deals with both. The start of Levi and Shlishi is the same either way.

Comment: @Michoel I'd have to see it inside, but it could be that the siddur is not specifying how to split up the aliyot when split in three but only how to do it when done in 5. Certainly the way I've always seen it in Israel is the way JNF describes, but that's no proof.

Comment: @DoubleAA [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=1008) is the Hebrew/English version of the siddur - it only deals with outside Israel. In the Hebrew only version (I couldn't find it online), Levi and Shlishi start in the same place in Israel and outside Israel, but in Israel Shlishi continues till the end of the reading.

Comment: @Michoel, my Siddur (רנת ישראל) brings the pesach Aliya between Pesach to Sefirat Ha'Omer (5 Psukim after yours). My father שיח' said maybe the idea was to put Pesach, the current Chag, in the first Aliya and have Omer which is _Mitzvas Hayom_ start the next Aliya.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36571/why-is-the-torah-reading-for-minor-fast-days-different-by-just-one-verse-from-wh